# How to save a google maps edited polygon path in Vue

Tags: google-maps, vue.js, vue-component, polygon

I have a Vue component BaseMap that contains a marker component Location.
The Location component has a Polygon marker that can be edtited.

```
// BaseMap
<GmapMap>
  <Location :location="location" />
</GmapMap>


// Location
<gmap-marker>
  <gmap-polygon
    ref="polyMarker"
    :editable="true"
    :path="location.path"
    @mouseup="updatePath('polyMarker')"
  />
</gmap-marker>

<script>

  methods: {
   updatePath(ref_name){
     console.log(this.$refs[ref_name].path) // same array as origin
   }
  }

</script>
```

How do I access the new edited points of the polygon? If I use this.$ref.polyMarker.path I keep getting the original array of points not the new ones.

### EDIT

After discussion with MrUpsidown I went ahead and coded the minimum app in codesandbox. The same problem exist.

```
Dependancies:
- vue
- vue2-gmap-cuspom-marker

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// main.js
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import * as VueGoogleMaps from "vue2-google-maps";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

Vue.use(VueGoogleMaps, {
  load: {
    //    libraries: "places", // This is required if you use the Autocomplete plugin
    key: "[USE YOUR OWN KEY]"
  }
  //  autobindAllEvents: false,
  //  installComponents: true
});
new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");


//////////////////////////////////////////
//App.vue

<template>
  <div id="app">
    <HelloWorld />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
}
</style>


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// HelloWorld.vue

<template>
  <div>
    <baseMap/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import baseMap from "@/components/baseMap";

export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  components: { baseMap },
  props: {
    msg: String
  }
};
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style>
</style>


////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//baseMap.vue

<template>
  <div>
    <GmapMap :style="'height:500px'" :center="center" :zoom="zoom">
      <Location :location="location"/>
    </GmapMap>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Location from "@/components/Location";

export default {
  name: "baseMap",
  components: { Location },
  data: function() {
    return {
      center: { lat: -33.9249, lng: 18.4241 },
      zoom: 12,
      location: {
        path: [
          { lat: -33.91170210440241, lng: 18.422548745513268 },
          { lat: -33.90993912517883, lng: 18.422806237578698 },
          { lat: -33.90874597713464, lng: 18.42422244393856 },
          { lat: -33.90482806012767, lng: 18.42952248895199 },
          { lat: -33.90073186345211, lng: 18.42428681695492 },
          { lat: -33.90128397100101, lng: 18.420596097350426 },
          { lat: -33.90256627151344, lng: 18.417656396270104 },
          { lat: -33.90367045927834, lng: 18.416454766631432 },
          { lat: -33.90532671411109, lng: 18.417913888335534 },
          { lat: -33.908389810302396, lng: 18.413579438567467 },
          { lat: -33.91084733115123, lng: 18.41703412377865 },
          { lat: -33.91170210440241, lng: 18.422548745513268 }
        ]
      }
    };
  },
  props: {
    msg: String
  }
};
</script>

<style>
</style>



/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Location.vue

<template>
  <div>
    <gmap-marker>
      <gmap-polygon
        ref="polyMarker"
        :editable="true"
        :path="location.path"
        @mouseup="updatePath('polyMarker')"
      />
    </gmap-marker>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import GmapCustomMarker from "vue2-gmap-custom-marker";

export default {
  name: "Location",
  components: {
    GmapCustomMarker
  },
  props: {
    location: {
      type: Object,
      default() {
        return {};
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updatePath(name) {
      console.log(this.$refs[name].path);
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Comment: Which Vue Google Maps package are you using? Please provide a [mcve] that allows to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @MrUpsidown I'm using 'vue2-gmap-custom-marker' that runs on a vue_element_admin framework. Am right in assuming that the this.$refs[ref_name].path should change as the polygon change?

Comment: Try `@paths_changed` on the `<gmap-polygon>` with a method of yours (just like you did for `@mouseup`). Maybe check [this example](https://github.com/xkjyeah/vue-google-maps/blob/vue2/examples/polygon-editing.html).

Comment: @MrUpsidown I have coded the minimum code to make the the app work in codesanbox (added it to the original post) and I am getting the same problem. I had a look at the example that you gave me, but it use event listeners in a single file. How do I implement that in a component based system?

Comment: Don't you want to share a link to the code sandbox?

Comment: @MrUpsidown sure https://codesandbox.io/s/polygon-edit-wu7lr?fontsize=14 You will have to enter your own Google Maps API key on main.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First replace `:path` with `:paths`:

```
:paths="location.path"
```

Then replace the `@mouseup` event with `@paths_changed` using `$event` as parameter:

```
@paths_changed="updatePath($event)"
```

Finally log your path; you'll see how it's getting updated now.

```
updatePath(mvcArray) {
  for (let i = 0; i < mvcArray.getLength(); i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < mvcArray.getAt(i).getLength(); j++) {
      console.log(mvcArray.getAt(i).getAt(j).lat() + "," + mvcArray.getAt(i).getAt(j).lng());
    }
  }
  console.log("-------")
}
```

For further guidance I recommend you check out the library's examples such as [this one](https://github.com/xkjyeah/vue-google-maps/blob/vue2/examples/polygon-editing.html).

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Glad to hear & happy to help! :)